# series parallel graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E) $ be a series parallel graph ([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series-parallel_graph)) with terminals $s,t \in V$

I am trying to prove the follwowing two statements.

> 1. Let $e \in E$ be an edge and $G'$ be the graph obtained by adding a parallel edge to e. Then $G$ is an sp-graph if and only if $G'$ is an sp graph
> 2. Let $e \in E$ be any edge $e=u-v$. The graph $G'$ obtained by 'splitting' the edge (adding another vertex x so we have the path u-x-v) is a sp-graph if and only if $G$ is an sp -graph

I don't know how to prove the general case ($e$ an arbitrary edge) but if we take $e=(s,t)$ then I add a parallel edge to $e$ by doing parallel composition with the "base"-graph (graph only containing the edge $(s,t$) or a series composition for 2)

How do I prove the general case ?

Would appreciate any tips/hints/help

Comment: I don’t think there is a simple way to do this without a full structural description of two-terminal sp graphs in one form or another. One way is to use the sp-tree which is a binary tree whose leaves are copies of $K_2$ and whose internal nodes are either the series or parallel connection of its two children. Given such a tree, you can find the leaf equal to $e$ and either duplicate it or subdivide it by turning it into the right kind of internal node.

Comment: Another way is to show that a two-terminal sp graph is a two-terminal so graph with respect to the endpoints of any edge, but this requires essentially the same work as above.